# Ember.js Data - Issues with nested data types

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to ember and I'm pulling back some JSON via `DS.RESTAdapter()` which looks like:

`{"apis":[{"id":"0",name:"test",methods:[{"id":"0","name":"test"},{"id:"1","name":"test2"}]}]}`

My models:

```
App.Api = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    methods: DS.hasMany('App.ApiMethod')
});

App.ApiMethod = DS.Model.extend({
    api: DS.belongsTo('App.Api'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I can read the `Api` model properties fine but if I try and loop through the methods property, it's empty. I've also tried passing in `{ embedded: true }` as an option in the `DS.hasMany()` call.

Any ideas?

Comment: I eventually came to the conclusion that Ember is shit and the docs are poor. I moved to Angular and love it.

Answer (score 0):

you aren't using the default rest format for nested models -> http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships